# Package update after delete cache in NuGet.Server v2.11.2.0

Tags: nuget, nuget-server

I am using latest NuGet.Server v2.11.2.0 as a my local repository.It hosted at my local system.
My problem is that newly added package is not listed while refresh the link.
For example In my server Packages folder has 5 .nuget package.But when i add new one , It will not show after the link refresh.

It will show the new one after deleting "aatfsbuild.cache.bin" file from server packages.
Pleaese suggest the way to add new package without delete file.

http://localhost:57958/nuget/Packages

Thanks,
Mahen

Comment: I often have this problem. Sometimes it will work for a period of time and then suddenly stop working. When it starts working again, I haven't yet been able to figure out why.

Comment: I've also deleted the cache, and it has no effect.